# How to default to a datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint, list

How to setup Sharepoint to default to a datasheet view for a particular list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new View from the list's Settings / Create View menu. Select 'Datasheet View' as the view format and then tick the 'Make this the default view' option.

Alternatively if the correct view already exists then select the View from the List's Settings screen and tick the 'Make this the default view' option.